# Service with abstract model initiation

Tags: java, architecture, abstraction, services

I want to implement an abstract module to store credits and I have the following structure:

Model: Credit (abstract)
Dao: CreditDao (interface)
Service: CreditService

The Credit model should be implemented in the application which is using the module. The application can choose how the model is stored in any database.

But the problem is that I have to initiate instances, but I can't because it's abstract.

Well, my solutions are:

1. Create a abstract method in the service (for example createModel) but I want to avoid an abstract Service.
2. Create a abstract method in the dao to create the model. (I prefer this way)
3. A own class for initiate the model CreditFactory (The application have to implement this)

But my question is, is there any other way which is better. Maybe a pattern which I don't know?

I am new in the java world, maybe generics is the keyword. Probably I have to use generics.

I would love to hear your solutions.

Comment: By "i have to initiate instances", do you mean that you need to initialize Credit models from within the CreditService class? If so, why?

Comment: CreditService have a method addCredit(CreditAttachable, Amount). The service asks the CreditDao if there is any Credit object stored in db. If not CreditService have to create one.

Comment: Ok. Now another question: why your Credit model is abstract? What different stuff could the application implement on concrete instances of this model that could be used within the Service? Only additional properties to be persisted, or also additional logic?

Comment: Additional properties and the way how it is stored. For example different databases. I want to avoid a dependency to hibernate. 

For any additional logic it is required to extend the CreditService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions:

- Remove the abstract from your Credit model. **Why**: your core application (credit app) must work independently from any client and any database. You should be able to unit test it without UI or DB. Therefore, the database ideally should be a plugin to your core app (registered by any specific application of your core business rules). That, your core application must define what a Credit model is, regardless of any database
- Your service should receive instances of Credit from the client. According to your example, the client should be perfectly able to call the service method passing some Credit to it.
- Implement as many data access layer as necessary. Since you already defined a Dao interface, it is easy to make the DB a plugin to your app. Now, create some e.g. HibernateDataAccess layer for your data and implement all the specifics for persistence in this library (again: these specifics shouldn't be within the Credit model -- which is why you said to me it was abstract)
- Create an application, and in this application's entry point, you "register" to your service the ICreditDao object (via dependency injection) that will be responsible for persistence of Credit models of your app.

Please note that these suggestions are not strictly related to Java. For more info, take a look at 'Clean Architecture' from Bob Martin (https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html)

EDIT: here I'll try to provide some sample code in order to illustrate my points and to answer all of your questions.

**CreditCoreLibrary project**

```
//Defines a model for Credit, to be used by a client application
public class Credit {
   //...attributes
   public CreditAttachable getCreditAttachable() {
        ///...
   }
   public double getAmount() {
        ///...
   }
}

//Needs to be implemented by another library, to be used by
//the client application
public interface CreditDao {
    void SaveOrCreate(Credit credit);
    IList<Credit> getAll();
}

public class CreditService {

    private CreditDao creditDao;

    public CreditService(CreditDao creditDao) {
        //The service relies on the concrete implementation of
        //the Dao, provided by the client app
        this.creditDao = creditDao;
    }

    //Methods receive and return Credit models defined in this core library
    public void AddCredit(Credit credit) {
        creditDao.SaveOrCreate(credit);
    }

    public IList<Credit> GetCreditList() {
        return creditDao.GetAll();
    }
}
```

**CreditHibernateDataAccessLibrary project**

Here's a xml mapping file that binds a column in DB to a property in the class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the employee detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="salary" column="salary" type="int"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is a specific Dao implementation, that uses Hibernate api:

```
public class HBCreditDao implements CreditDao {
    //...uses Hibernate API to perform CRUD on your DB
    //...which will use the mapping xml file to be able
    //to create Credit objects based on DB data
}
```

**MyApplication project (could be a web app, or even a console app)**

```
//This is just an example, but it means that in your application
//entry point, you need to "register" the Daos used by your app
//in the Service
int main() {

    //This project uses CreditHibernateDataAccessLibrary.jar
    HBCreditDao myDao = new HBCreditDao();

    //This project uses CreditCoreLibrary.jar
    //This injects a specific Dao object into the service
    CreditService service = new CreditService(myDao);

    //Perform operations using the service
    IList<Credit> creditList = service.GetCreditList();
}
```

**PLUS:** see more about Hibernate mapping files (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_files.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your help and detailed answer. I don´t understand your solution in detail, but the blog posts looks interesting. I will read it and try to answer the remaining questions by myself.

Comment: Well i read the blog post and i try to understand it in detail. But i´am not sure if it´s clear for me right now, sorry for annoying ;)
I will remove the abstract from my Credit model to define what the Credit model is.
First question: Probably i have to create a Credit entity which defines db structure, extra fields etc., correct? Does this entity extend the Core model to support the interface?
I will implement the HibernateDataAccess which implements the CreditDao and inject it to the CreditService.

Comment: Second question: The HibernateDataAccess implementation will do the converting to a Credit entity on save?
Third question: On get operations the HibernateDataAccess will return the Credit entity?

Well now the interfaces only work with Credit model but i can cast to Credit entity if i have to (in the application which implements the module).

Comment: First: no additional entity; just mapping file (see above); Second: no entity; no conversion; Third: the concrete Dao returns/receives the model instance.

Comment: Perfect, now it´s clear. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is it possible to provide the mapping informations annotation based?

Comment: @MallorcaSoftware to be honest, I've only used NHibernate (the port of hibernate for .NET), on which is possible to 'code' the mappings using the fluent approach. I know that the XML is not the only way available; I guess in the link I provided they mention ways to generate the mapping files for you classes.

Comment: Well after a quick search I think it is possible to use annotations for the mappíngs: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/